# Gridbox to conform to content size

Tags: css, vue.js, css-grid

So I have this simple table here:[image]

The code for which is fairly straightforward:

```
<template>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table__headers">
            <h3 v-for="header in headers" :key="header.value">
                {{ header.value }}
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="table__body">
            <div
                v-for="(item, index) in modelData"
                :key="index"
                class="table__body--line"
            >
                <p v-for="{ property } in headers" :key="property">
                    <router-link
                        :to="{ name: 'AdminJob', params: { id: item.id } }"
                    >
                        {{ item[property] }}
                    </router-link>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <Pagination
        v-model:current-page="meta.currentPage"
        :total="meta.total"
        v-model:per-page="meta.perPage"
    />
</template>


<style scoped lang="scss">
.table {
    border: solid 1px red;

    &__headers {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        grid: 50px / auto-flow minmax(100px, 1fr);
    }

    &__body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        &--line {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 10px;
            grid: auto / auto-flow minmax(200px, 1fr);
        }
    }
}
</style>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to make the width of the column be flexible to the content inside of it.

So in the base above, since **Details** has so much more content then **Status** it would fill out more space. The other caveat is that this Vue component shows many different tables of information. In other cases, we may have only 2 columns and in other situations we may have 8, so I'm trying to figure out a 'global' solution to this without going into each table and tinkering with the widths.

Is there a simpler way to do this in Grid? I gave Flexbox a try but I couldn't get the columns to align perfectly like in Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For columns flexibility you can use `css-variables` and bind it with Vue's style binding.

```
<template>
  <div class="table" :style="{ '--cols': counts }">
    <div v-for="header in headers" :key="header">
      <h3 class="table__headers">{{ header }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      headers: [
        "apple",
        "ndis officia! Perferendis ratione blanditiis repellat explicabo neque",
        "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "mango"
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    counts: function () { return this.headers.length < 4 ? `${l}` : "auto-fit" },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), minmax(100px, max-content));
  gap: 10px;
}
.table__headers { ... }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `grid-template-columns:min-content` in your code.
this [page](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/NMyGNY) can help you.